# Coffee script path.exists deprecated notice from node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, deprecated

- OSX 10.6
- CoffeeScript 1.2.0
- node.js v0.7.7-pre

I am seeing a deprecation notice every time I run the coffee command.  The notice is this:

```
path.exists is deprecated. It is now called `fs.exists`.
```

I know that this is happening because node.js deprecated path.exists.  See

https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/2587

I would think there would be a lot of info about this but all I can see is some indirect reference relating to a more serious issue saying it's not going to be 'fixed':

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2113

Am I the only one having this problem?  Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can make this go away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/lib/coffee-script/command.js#L323

There are references to `path.exists` in the coffeescript source code.

Note that that in node 0.6 (the current stable version) `fs.exists` is null so it's difficult to cleanly upgrade this.

We have an issue where the same source code doesn't work in both 0.6 and 0.7.

I would assume that we wait for 0.8 and then someone will upgrade coffeescript to use `fs.exists` and deprecate 0.6 support

Answer (score 3):

When waiting for 0.8, on OSX you can temporary fix this issue by replacing all `path.exists` to `fs.exists` in file (if you install globally):

`/opt/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js`

Don't forget to use root access when editing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a late answer, but there is a patching module meant to temporarily fix this problem until everyone has a chance to update there code.

https://github.com/SportZing/node-exists-patch

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just change all the instances of that in the source code?

Comment: I suppose.  Seems like a last resort for various reasons.  I would rather not have to maintain my own version of the code for something this trivial.  If I say it's trivial you might wonder why I even asked the question...but I'm doing a CS compile in my rails tests and this message is printing out dozens of times with my test output and it's annoying.  It's only trivial in the sense that it doesn't affect the workings of CS.